# Haskell multiply arguments if odd

Tags: haskell

I want my code to read numbers from the console arguments and write the even ones back to the console. The odd ones should be multiplied by 2 to make them even as well. For this I added the method evenify which checks with mod 2 if its odd or even.

I just can't find the error I'm making, most likely it's just a syntax error somewhere. Here is my code as of now:

```
import System.Environment

evenify :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
evenify n = if mod n 2 == 0 then n else n*2
main :: IO ()
main = getArgs >>= putStrLn . show . evenify . read . head
_ = main
```

What is the error?

Comment: How do you know there's an error? Is there an error message? Does it return the wrong value? Try to make it easy to help you.

Comment: What's this line doing? `_ = main`

Comment: Also, `print = putStrLn . show` for future reference.

Answer (score 2):

First problem is that `evenify` has the wrong type signature - as written it has the signature:

```
evenify :: Integer -> Integer
```

With this change your program works in the sense that it will process one command line argument - the first one only.

To process all of the arguments use `map`:

```
main = do args <- getArguments
          putStrLn $ show $ map evenify (map read args)
```

Explanation:

```
args                         is the list of command line arguments (Strings)
map read args                is a list of Integers
map evenify (map read args)  is the list of results
```

Answer (score 1):

first error that catches the eye

```
evenify :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
evenify n = if mod n 2 == 0 then n else n*2
```

signature expects a list but implementation is for scalars.